# Online database creation, mobile phone access and updates

Tags: database

END GOAL:
I volunteer with a non-profit (thus want to create not buy), have a website/host already, mostly mobile phone usage to update each other on info, existing spreadsheets have been ineffective. I would like to set up a password/login accessible database with differing levels of permissions to read or edit info and text/numerical info plus a picture for each record that is accessible from multiple mobile devices. I'd like to create the apps for each of these devices to login and access info, send updates of a record or download the latest record info. The database would be stored locally as well for offline access, and searchable/sortable.

PRELIMINARY GOAL:
Online database, single or multiple user access (with same level of permissions), only text/numerical info, update a single record from phone to database, update all "new" records to a device, iPhone only, local copy for offline access

QUESTION:
What types of databases can I use (I've seen "SQLite" thrown around)
How do I get the database online
How do I access the database online with login info
How do I pass info device to server and vice versa (seen the terms RESTful JSON API)
How do I setup the database and search on a device

Basically, I've dabbled in iPhone app dev and have an idea of what questions to search for to create that aspect, I have some logic laid out for "rules" for updating etc but I don't even know where to start or what questions to search for the database dev online, authentication, and passing info back and forth from a server to a device... I have only used Wordpress and done some HTML (ages ago) and minor c++ but don't really know what the acronyms are, if they are protocols or languages or programs...

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow; and will be invariably closed as "Primarily opinion based" or "Too broad". Please read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - if you want to refine your ideas then please go into the chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the question is extremely large. There are many options you will like and others you won't.

Personally, I would go with Ruby on Rails. Extremely easy to set up and learn, highly configurable. It is very easy to implement an API consumed through Json requests.

For the client side, you can either go with JavaScript and phonegap or develop a native iPhone app. Both will make json requests to your API.